# Apply timezone offset to datetime in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

For a given date string such as `2009-01-01T12:00:00+0100` I want the UTC datetime object.

```
from datetime import datetime 
datetime.strptime("2013-03-21T14:19:42+0100", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

returns

```
datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 21, 14, 19, 42, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)))
```

I cannot believe there is no method in `datetime` or `pandas` for applying the timezone-related offset to the datetime and returning plain UTC datetime.

How can I apply the `tzinfo` offset/delta, so that the resulting timezone is plain UTC (`tzinfo=None`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [`.astimezone()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) is what you want.

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
d = datetime.strptime("2013-03-21T14:19:42+0100", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z") # 2013-03-21 14:19:42+01:00
d.astimezone(timezone.utc) # 2013-03-21 13:19:42+00:00
```

`timezone.utc` is not an optional parameter in this case: The [documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone)

> If called without arguments (or with `tz=None`) the system local
> timezone is assumed for the target timezone.

This can lead to unintended behaviour (depending on your local timezone).

Comment: It depends: Documentation says "If called without arguments (or with `tz=None`) the system local timezone is assumed for the target timezone." Maybe you can add to your answer: `from datetime import datetime, timezone\n
d = datetime.strptime("2013-03-21T14:19:42+0100", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")\n
d.astimezone(timezone.utc)`

Comment: Sorry I edited the answer myself. :)

Comment: @MichaelDorner Yes, you are correct, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This feels a bit dirty but it does work

```
from datetime import datetime
orig_dt = datetime.strptime("2013-03-21T14:19:42+0100", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")  # datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 21, 14, 19, 42, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)))
utc_time_value = orig_dt - orig_dt.utcoffset()
utc_dt = utc_time_value.replace(tzinfo=None)  # datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 21, 13, 19, 42)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I really hoped there is a built-in method to do this. I cannot imaging that this an uncommon intention, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

Here's is an actual code (built-in):

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

return datetime(yy, mm, dd, hh, min, ss, 0, timezone(timedelta(hours=5)))       # +0500
# or
return datetime(yy, mm, dd, hh, min, ss, 0, timezone(timedelta(seconds=18000))) # +0500
```